# Error on app launch: Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown (Xamarin iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I get this error message when launching my app:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[TableSource initWithCoder:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796e6fa0

I already searched on google, but didn't find a solution.

About the app: The App has a UITableView with some custom cells. The UITableView is on a normal "view". Theres also a Button on the normal "view", this button should (when touched) add a custom cell to the UITableView.

The UITableView has the name "tableView" and in properties at class "TableSource". The Button has the name "btn01" and in properties as class "ViewController".

The custom cells have as "reuse identifier" "Cell01Reuse", "Cell02Reuse", etc. And as class "Testclass" (which doesnt exist as a file).

The View Controller (the base, where everything is on) has "ViewController" as class.

I have two classes with code. First is "View Controller":

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace myapp
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            //UITableView _table;
            //_table = new UITableView
            //{
            //    Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, View.Bounds.Height * 0.03, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height * 0.80),
            //    Source = new TableSource(null)
            //};
            //_table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
            //View.AddSubview(_table);

            TableSource TS = new TableSource();

            btn01.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            {
                TS.updateTableView();
                string cell01 = "Cell01Reuse";
                TS.tableItems.Add(cell01);
            };
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

Second is "TableSource":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace myapp
{
    public partial class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {



        //string[] tableItems;
        public List<string> tableItems = new List<string>();
        public static string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        //public TableSource(string[] items)
        //{
        //    tableItems = items;
        //}

        public TableSource()
        {
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
            }
            cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row];
            tableItems.Add(Convert.ToString(cell));
            return cell;
        }

        public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return base.NumberOfSections(tableView);
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            new UIAlertView("Alert", "You touched: " + tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        }

        public void updateTableView()
        {
            tableView.updateTableView();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I can not reproduce the issue you met, your description is not clear enough, but there are some problem in you code is for sure, such as you should not return 0 in RowsInSection method, I can give you a sample to reference.(All the UI is created by code)

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    protected ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        CGRect tableFrame = this.View.Bounds;
        tableFrame.Y = 100;
        tableFrame.Height -= 100;
        UITableView tableView = new UITableView (tableFrame);
        this.View.AddSubview (tableView);

        MyTalbeSource mySource = new MyTalbeSource ();
        tableView.Source = mySource;
        tableView.ReloadData ();

        int count = 0;
        UIButton btnNew = new UIButton (UIButtonType.System);
        btnNew.Frame = new CGRect (20, 20, 100, 40);
        btnNew.SetTitle ("NewItem", UIControlState.Normal);
        btnNew.TouchUpInside += delegate {
            mySource.AddNewItem ("NewItem" + count++);
            tableView.ReloadData ();
        };
        this.Add (btnNew);
    }
}

class MyTalbeSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private const string CELL_ID = "MyTalbeCell";
    private List<string> dataList;

    public MyTalbeSource ()
    {
        dataList = new List<string> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            dataList.Add ("Test " + i.ToString ());
        }
    }

    public void AddNewItem (string title)
    {
        dataList.Add (title);
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return dataList.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        MyTableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CELL_ID) as MyTableCell;
        if (null == cell) {
            cell = new MyTableCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CELL_ID);
            cell.InitCell ();
        }
        cell.Text = dataList [indexPath.Row];
        return cell;
    }
}

class MyTableCell : UITableViewCell
{
    private UILabel lbInfo;

    public string Text { 
        get {
            return lbInfo.Text;
        }
        set {
            lbInfo.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public MyTableCell (UITableViewCellStyle style, string cellID) : base (style, cellID)
    {
    }

    public void InitCell ()
    {
        lbInfo = new UILabel ();
        lbInfo.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        this.AddSubview (lbInfo);
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        lbInfo.Frame = this.Bounds;
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Any question about Xamarin.iOS is welcome.

Comment: Helps a bit, but doesnt solve my problem. I dont know how to describe my situation better as above. But thank you!

Comment: Can you share your solution somewhere? Or give me more detail to help you. By the way, you should not make the UITableView as a property in your UITableSource.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I did manage to take another way to solve my "task". I used an example from Xamarin and built arround it.
Here's the example: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tables/custom-tableviewcell/

I dont have the problem anymore at the moment. Is there a way to message you somehow if i encounter this problem again (or a similar) again? Because you seem to know about Xamarin. Thanks again for your effort!

ps: i marked your post as answer because if i would still have the problem, you would have helped me to solve it.

Comment: Very happy to know that you solved your problem, if you have some question, just put it there. I'm not sure if stack allow user left their contact info.